# how to check where is url from? in views.py [Django]

Tags: python, django

this is my views.py I need to check where is the url from? to redirect to the correct url.
I try to use request.path and request.get_full_path but it's not working.

my views.py

```
def deletemovie(request,id):
    user=request.user.id
    movie = get_object_or_404(Reviewmovie,id=id)
    movie.delete()
    if request.path == 'report:report':
        return redirect('report:report')
    else:
        return redirect('movie:dashboard',user)
```

Comment: if you import reverse `from django.urls import reverse`, and then try `request.path == reverse('report:report')`?

Comment: @RHSmith159 It's still not working

Comment: what is the value of `request.path` and `reverse("report:report")`

Comment: @Tushortz
1.I think request.path use to get url like if url from report.html return to report.html
2.report:report is my path app_name="report",path("report",views.Report,name="report")

Comment: Show us your urls.py

Comment: ok sorry @Hagyn

Comment: This should work `request.path == reverse('report:report')`, check the value of both with prints maybe `request.path` is `/report/` and `reverse('report:report')` is `/report`.

Answer (score 0):

my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name='movie'

urlpatterns =[
    path('',views.Index, name='home'),
    path('movielist',views.Movielist, name="movielist"),
    path('addmovie',views.Addmovie,name="addmovie"),
    path('moviedetail/<int:id>/',views.Moviedetail, name="moviedetail"),
    path('categorypage/<int:id>/',views.Categorypage,name="categorypage"),
    path('dashboard/<int:id>',views.Dashboard,name="dashboard"),
    path('profile/<int:id>',views.Profile,name="profile"),
    path('Search',views.Search,name="Search"),
    path('deletemovie/<int:id>',views.deletemovie,name="deletemovie")
]
```

and another one

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'report'
urlpatterns=[
    path('report',views.Report, name='report'),
    path('report/<int:id>/delete', views.MemberDelete, name='memberdelete')

]
```